# How can I get and set pixel data in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, get, set, pixel

I have a texture2D where I want to get the color of a specified pixel. Do something with it and put a new color in an other texture2D.

I will need to do this with all the pixels in the texture. How can I do this.

No pixel shader's please. It need to be in C#

Comment: Isn't that what pixel shader's are for? Why wouldn't you want one?

Comment: How big are your textures? setting data onto a texture isn't too bad but getting data from a texture can be very slow...

Comment: I am trying to do a 2d water animation. Go here:http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_water.htm. The textures are not very big. I think that they are 400 x 300. I will keep experimenting to see how big I can make them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Texture2D`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.aspx) class contains the [`GetData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.getdata.aspx) and [`SetData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.setdata.aspx) methods that should do exactly what you want.

Comment: While this will do the trick, depending on what you're doing this can be very, very slow.

Comment: There are samples in the MSDN documentation that I linked to.

Comment: @dotTutorials: The `GetData` overloads have samples. `SetData` had samples when I posted the comment in 2011. I don't have any control over MSDN.

Comment: This is why you should not only answer by linking also give more explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.

When I was trying to get the color of a pixel the Alpha value of the color was 0. This means that the color would be completely transparent. To solve it I just needed to change the Alpha value to 255.

I think that this happened because I am using an jpg file. Jpg file's do not support Alpha values.